# Where do the scenes in the Dragonball Z English OP come from?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-movies

In the English Opening of Dragonball Z ([*Rock the Dragon*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-fLvdmUx6A)) i recall reading that [this scene of Krillin running](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-fLvdmUx6A&t=0m23s) came from either *The Tree of Might* or *The World's Strongest* movies when at first i thought that all the scenes were either original scenes or clips from episodes

So i am wondering what Scenes in the Rock the Dragon Opening are from what movies/episodes and what were originally made and were never seen in a movie or episode

Comment: I have some doubts about some shots, but I see scenes from The Tree of Might, the world's strongest, Dead Zone movie, the saiyan saga, Trunks saga. There are some Goku's kaioken power up that come from the world's strongest, but there is one in circular form I dont remember if I've ever seen it, may be it's from the Turles movie (Tree of Might) . Probably no original animation in that opening